# imageresizer vs2012 response code 404

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-7, http-status-code-404, windows-server-2008-r2, imageresizer

I get an HTTP 404 after installing imageresizer on windows 2008 server r2 x64. I installed the needed packages (e.g. IIS, Visual Studio) and tried to create an project. I didn't knew which type I should choose, so I choosed "empty project". I downloaded imageresizer and copied the needed library files to bin folder. I copied the Web.config in the document root directory. I then created a website with the IIS-manager and pointed the doc root directory to the project directory, where my Web.config lives.

I than started the webserver and tried to access the server using firefox. Anyways, I get an HTTP 404 response code with this request body:

```
Not Found
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Did you add an image to the project, and try to access that URL? Did you look at the ImageResizer diagnostics page?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I created an amazon ec2 instance with an beanstalk application container and created an empty asp.net site with. Its working now. But I get another error, when trying to connect to resizer.debug.ashx:

`Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'.
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5477; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.547`

Strange, because I installed VS2012 Ultimate with .NET 4.5. Anything I missed?

Comment: [...]empty asp.net site with vs2012[...]

Comment: You configured the ASP.NET Application Pool to use 2.0 instead of 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh...I missed to copy the Web.config file from the BasicIISExample Application. I'm just getting a warning about adding DiskCache or CDN support. Anyways, its working like a charm now. Awesome software. :)